# Twilio Multiple Recipient

Tags: python-3.x, api, sms, twilio

I want to send a SMS to multiple recipient in Twilio API.
But the problem is I'm getting the same SMS twice in the first number only.

Here's the code

```
  from twilio.rest import Client

  account = "AC6ac96158bda1b5d814035373b8b64329"
  token = "f761d8b7a336aa746dbb533053a0ae74"
  client = Client(account, token)
  num=['+88016742XXXXX','+8801937XXXXXX']

  for i in range(0,len(num)):
        message = client.messages.create(num[i], from_="+1667XXXXXX6",
                             body="Hello ")
```

Answer (score 4):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

This might be because you're not sending the `to` argument correctly in your call. You can also simplify your loop by looping through the items in `num` rather than using a range and an index into `num`.

Try this:

```
for number in num:
    message = client.messages.create(to=number, from_="+1667XXXXXX6", body="Hello")
    print(message.sid)
```

Comment: Good stuff! What was it? In case others have the same issue.

Comment: Well,at first I wasn't able to send SMS to multiple recipient ;because of number verification. Then after verification it worked . That's it

Comment: Ah, number verification. Of course! Glad you got it sorted.

Comment: The argument name should be `from_`.  The line should read: `message = client.messages.create(to=number, from_="+1667XXXXXX6", body="Hello")`

Comment: @philnash What if some of the recipient number does not associated with whatsapp then how they will get the message?

Comment: @RahulVerma you should only send WhatsApp messages to users who have explicitly opted in to receive them ([see the documentation here](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017773294-Rules-and-Best-Practices-for-WhatsApp-Messaging-on-Twilio#h_06ee4910-7d2a-4587-af05-ec76af5ab25d)). That way you should know ahead of time whether their number is a WhatsApp number.